# Get route list from parent route group in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Here is the simple routing code: (i take it from official site just for example)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {

    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {

    });
});
```

Is it possible to get all routes from this group programmatically? Thank you.

Comment: If shell command is enough, then you can use `php artisan route:list`. This will list all routes and the HTTP methods used to invoke it, the controllers which each route will handle and which middleware it belongs to.

Comment: @JTheDev Thank you for answer. Is it possible to get same information from controller?

Comment: sorry nothing is coming to my mind. `Artisan::call('route:list') ;` is also returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this function will help you..

In Routes.php file --

```
Route::get('routes', function() {

       \Artisan::call('route:list');
       echo '<pre>'; print_r(\Artisan::output());

});
```